# creating a league planer

Tags: python, excel

i am newly in a position, where i have to plan the hole season for my bowling association. So i wanted to write a program to do this for me automatically.
So we currently have 7 leagues with 6 teams they play 6 times per season and currently at 3 different bowling alleys which should be used equally
1 center is bigger than the others so there should be 2 leagues at once the rest only fits one league at a time. Between each match day there should be 3 or 4 weeks an in dezember there arent any matches.
Sometimes the alleys are already booked so these dates should be minded as well.

these are my starting conditions
the plan should now link date of play alley and link togheter to create the season plan

instinctive i thought this has to be some sort of optimizationproblem but i have actually no clue how to find a starting point (what do i want to optimize and what funktion to use)
ideally i would build this in open office calc but i would mind a starting point for a program in python as well

currently i just listed the mentioned dates above in a calc sheet as im totally clueless where my starting point could be

Comment: Welcome to SO. Note that SO is for helping solve coding problems. It is not a code-for-hire site. For asking questions please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you'd want to paste some kind of code you've been working on for this kind of question, but because you're new, here's a freebie.

We'll use old school object oriented programming and create a `dict` to represent each league. We'll keep track of how many matches each league has played, and when their last match was. We'll also keep track of how many matches have been played on each alley. While there are matches to play, we'll find leagues that have had sufficient rest, then pick alleys in order of previous use. We'll then just match up the leagues and alleys and update the bookkeeping.

```
LEAGUES = {"League " + str(i): {'matches_played': 0, 'last_match':-999} for i in range(1, 8)}
NUM_MATCHES_TO_PLAY = 6
WEEKS_BETWEEN = 3
ALLEYS = {i: 0 for i in ['Alley A, Left', 'Alley A, Right', 'Alley B']}
week = 1
weeks = {}


while any(LEAGUES[league]['matches_played'] < NUM_MATCHES_TO_PLAY for league in LEAGUES):
    valid_leagues = [league for league in LEAGUES if LEAGUES[league]['last_match'] <= week - WEEKS_BETWEEN]
    weeks[week] = list(zip(valid_leagues, sorted(ALLEYS, key=lambda x: ALLEYS[x])))
    for (league, alley) in weeks[week]:
        LEAGUES[league]['matches_played'] += 1
        LEAGUES[league]['last_match'] = week
        ALLEYS[alley] += 1
    week += 1

for week in weeks:
    print("Week", week, "Matches", weeks[week])
```

Yields:

```
Week 1 Matches [('League 1', 'Alley A, Left'), ('League 2', 'Alley A, Right'), ('League 3', 'Alley B')]
Week 2 Matches [('League 4', 'Alley A, Left'), ('League 5', 'Alley A, Right'), ('League 6', 'Alley B')]
Week 3 Matches [('League 7', 'Alley A, Left')]
Week 4 Matches [('League 1', 'Alley A, Right'), ('League 2', 'Alley B'), ('League 3', 'Alley A, Left')]
Week 5 Matches [('League 4', 'Alley A, Right'), ('League 5', 'Alley B'), ('League 6', 'Alley A, Left')]
Week 6 Matches [('League 7', 'Alley A, Right')]
Week 7 Matches [('League 1', 'Alley B'), ('League 2', 'Alley A, Left'), ('League 3', 'Alley A, Right')]
Week 8 Matches [('League 4', 'Alley B'), ('League 5', 'Alley A, Left'), ('League 6', 'Alley A, Right')]
Week 9 Matches [('League 7', 'Alley B')]
Week 10 Matches [('League 1', 'Alley A, Left'), ('League 2', 'Alley A, Right'), ('League 3', 'Alley B')]
Week 11 Matches [('League 4', 'Alley A, Left'), ('League 5', 'Alley A, Right'), ('League 6', 'Alley B')]
Week 12 Matches [('League 7', 'Alley A, Left')]
Week 13 Matches [('League 1', 'Alley A, Right'), ('League 2', 'Alley B'), ('League 3', 'Alley A, Left')]
Week 14 Matches [('League 4', 'Alley A, Right'), ('League 5', 'Alley B'), ('League 6', 'Alley A, Left')]
Week 15 Matches [('League 7', 'Alley A, Right')]
Week 16 Matches [('League 1', 'Alley B'), ('League 2', 'Alley A, Left'), ('League 3', 'Alley A, Right')]
Week 17 Matches [('League 4', 'Alley B'), ('League 5', 'Alley A, Left'), ('League 6', 'Alley A, Right')]
Week 18 Matches [('League 7', 'Alley B')]
```

Comment: thank you very much this will be a great starting point for me and was much more than i actually asked for or expected big thanks